# How do I set up google analytics for each of my firebase sites in a single project?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have multiple hosted sites within a single firebase project. Currently in the google analytics section of firebase I can only see the data for my primary hosted site. I would like to be able to view the google analytics results from each of these sites individually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

However, each Hosting site has a separate "Stream" in Analytics.

This allows you to filter (via the "Add Filter +" button) the Analytics results by "Stream" in order to look at the analytics of one or multiple sites at the same time.

[image: screenshot of the Stream filter selection dialog]